# Can I configure sudo to print the command to be run?

Tags: sudo

Before giving authorization to run a command with elevated privileges, I would like to check what command `sudo` understood - be it because I'm running a script that calls `sudo`, or because I'm using variables/escaping/subshells in my command.

**Is there a way to ask `sudo` to print the command that it is about to run when it asks me for my user password?**

Something like this:

```
$ sudo some command with parameters
sudo: about to run ``some command with parameters``
Password:
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo -l <somecommand> <someparameters>
```

If a command is specified and is permitted by the security policy, the fully-qualified path to the command is displayed along with any command line arguments.

Here's an excerpt from `man sudo`

```
-l, --list  If no command is specified, list the allowed (and forbidden) commands for the invoking user (or the user speci‐
                 fied by the -U option) on the current host.  A longer list format is used if this option is specified multiple
                 times and the security policy supports a verbose output format.

                 If a command is specified and is permitted by the security policy, the fully-qualified path to the command is
                 displayed along with any command line arguments.  If command is specified but not allowed, sudo will exit with
                 a status value of 1.
```

Comment: Note that it doesn't run the command though.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `set -x' before the sudo invoke.

```
[steve@centos8 ~]$ cat x1
#!/bin/bash
echo foo
set -x
sudo id
set +x
echo bar
[steve@centos8 ~]$ ./x1
foo
+ sudo id
[sudo] password for steve:
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
+ set +x
bar
[steve@centos8 ~]$
```

Answer (score -1):

sudo does not provide this functionality, what you can do is define a function :

```
echo_run(){
    echo "About to run [$@]"
    "$@"
}

# Then you can do : echo_run sudo vim test.sh
```

Comment: Actually sudo DOES provide this functionality. See `man sudo` check the -l switch..

Comment: OP wants to print "About to run" and actually run the command, does -l switch do that ?

Comment: It looks to me like what the OP wants to know is "Is there a way to ask sudo to print the command that it is about to run when it asks me for my user password?" Did I miss something?

Comment: OP wrote `sudo: about to run "some command with parameters"`, reason why I think he wanted to RUN the command. When you type `sudo -l ls`, sudo does NOT run `ls` command.